# "Return" stdout to browser without exiting from any function in Flask

Tags: python, flask, stdout, fabric

I am using a mix of Python Flask (to trigger the process) and Fabric (to automate the tasks on remote machines).

I have tried using **yield** keyword and successfully managed to display the output for a sample program in Flask but without Fabric.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, Response
import pexpect
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/getdata')
def getdata():
    def meh():
        child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')
        child.sendline('mysh.sh')
        child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
        child.expect(' press [Enter]')
        child.interact()
        child.expect(pexpect.EOF)

        for line in iter(sys.stdout.readline,''):
            yield line.rstrip() + '\n'

    return Response(meh(), mimetype='text/html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Could someone point me in the direction i should be looking to get this done? So that the stdout of each fabric run(command) be displayed to the browser in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, If you meant 'realtime' not just run time, you would probably want to do is look a bit more at your framework, where if you want the data returned real-time (like as in like in a build tool etc).

To do this, you could run the fabric as a seperate async task (using some framework like celery etc), and dump the results from fabric back into a queue / pipe / database / whatever. Then have your original thread return from that either with repeat requests or with a repeat queue.

---

However to just call fabric from your data, fabric (or if you really wanted to, Paramiko (which is hte library which fabric wraps around)) can just be called from your code, i.e. not using the shell to call `fab foo`.

When calling run(), you can retrieve the output of the std out/std err of the command being run... Paramiko is a little less well documented (which is why fabric is so awesome to use), but if you have a look at this blog: 
http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different this contains a bunch of information:

Basically, the example from there is:

```
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', username='jesse', password='lol')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("uptime")

x = stdout.readlines()
```

value of x --> ['13:35  up 11 days,  3:13, 4 users, load averages: 0.14 0.18 0.16\n']

This would be trivial to add to your flask, but it won't be *realtime*, i.e. your flask and server will buffer it, and return the whole lot at the end of the process to the browser, assuming the browser hasn't timed out.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I will try using celery and let you know.

Comment: What worked for me was that I "yielded" the stdout.readlines() and with onprogress of an ajax function, I could get the output returned on the console. Thanks for the pointer :)